# how to integrate TinyMCE 4 with File responsive manager

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce-4

I try to integrate the File responsive manager  with TinyMCE 4,After I read and follow  DOCUMENTATION from [http://www.responsivefilemanager.com](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) how to install and integrate File responsive manager with TinyMCE 4. my folder structure become like this image [image].

I also have copy  tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager folder to tinymce/plugins/. so my tinymce/plugins/ folder like this image
[image]

I dont configure filemanager/config/config.php, i just add uploads folder as you can see in my first image above, the folder config in the filemanager/config/config.php like this

```
'base_url' => ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && ! in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']), array( 'off', 'no' ))) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
'upload_dir' => '/uploads/',
'current_path' => '../uploads/',
'thumbs_base_path' => '../thumbs/',
```

In my informasi_input.php i set `tinymce.init` like from the documentation

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       tinymce.init({
          selector: "#isi",theme: "modern",width: 680,height: 300,
          plugins: [
          "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
          ],
          toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft   aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
           toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
            image_advtab: true ,

            external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
            filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
            external_plugins: { "filemanager" :  "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
           });
         </script>
```

My html code for my form

```
 <p>
  Judul <br /><textarea name="judul" id="judul" cols="55" rows="2" required="required"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
 Pengantar <br />
  <textarea name="pengantar" id="pengantar" cols="55" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
 Isi <br />
  <textarea name="isi" id="isi" cols="55" rows="9" required="required"></textarea>
```

When i call the php file from localhost, i get my text area wihout editor text, like this image

[image]

I try to remove the code

```
  external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
  filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
  external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
```

from `tinymce.init` function in my php file (informasi_input.php)
I get my tinymce back like this image but without file  responsive manager

[image]

So any help whats wrong, is there wrong with my `tinymce.init` function code?

Answer (score 0):

With many trial i have solve my problem, with edit two line code from my `tinymce.init` function

before:

```
external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
... ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"
```

after:

```
external_filemanager_path:"/cpanel/filemanager/",
... ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/cpanel/filemanager/plugin.min.js"
```